# Dreamweaver can't save php file?

Tags: php, utf-8, dreamweaver

Dreamweaver can't save php file.

The error message says:

> The document's current encoding can not correctly save all the characters within the document you may want to change it to UTF-8 or an encoding that support spacial characters in this document.

How can I save the file to run?

Comment: copy the whole content to a new Dreamweaver page and try save.

Answer (score 12):

Open the file in Dreamweaver, I have CS5. Modify --> Page Properties --> Title/Encoding , use the Encoding DD to change it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 5):

You should save your php file in UTF-8 format. You can refer this [link](http://hsmoore.com/blog/how-to-save-a-dreamweaver-document-as-utf8/) for the details.

Answer (score 2):

if you're on windows, just use notepad to open the php file and do "Save as", change the encoding type to "UTF-8", and that should hopefully fix the problem. I ran into that a long time ago as well.

Answer (score 0):

An old post though but might help someone. I got the same problem and a trick worked for me.

1. Add this meta tag somewhere in file and Save the file. It will be saved correctly

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   ```
2. Remove the above added meta tag and save it again. It will go fine again.

Comment: I don't think it would work, since the `meta` only gives browsers a clue to what encoding to choose, which are mostly defaulted as UTF8. OP's problem is he can't even save it.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to use Tamizh fonts for my webpage, I used the `UNICODE`s to display as well as to store the values in the MySQL database. I just inserted the `UNICODE` strings into the database and fetched as ordinary strings.

Sample UNICODE:

```
 &#x0BA4;&#x0BAE;&#x0BBF;&#x0BB4;&#x0BCD;
```

=

தமிழ்

Answer (score 0):

Added this to the top of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Worked!

Comment: Actually, the W3 organization suggest using `<!DOCTYPE html>` for HTML 5

Answer (score 0):

> After adding  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` is not worked for me But what worked for me is following steps
>    Go to modify->Page Properties->Title/Encoding->Document Type(DTD) XHTML 1.O Transitional ->Encoding Unicode(UTF-8) ->Unicode Normalization Form c(Canonial Decomposition , followed by Canonial Composition) -> then check include unicode_signature(BOM)
>   Apply and ok

Answer (score 0):

If you have such an error when saving your php file

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2O5r.png)
it is possible that an XML tag is used in your code that includes a special encoding attribute.

For example: **xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"**

**In this case, you need to change this piece of code**